# run processing.js on azure web sites

Tags: azure, processing

I made a projessing.js application. It works fine in localhost. However, when I deploy my project into my Azure website projessing.js is unable to find my sketch (.pde) file.This is the error message that I get from chrome's console ;

Uncaught Processing.js: Unable to load pjs sketch files: pde/Letter/Letter.pde ==> Invalid XHR status 404

I searched this problem and I found this post about it but I don't know how to make a configuration to my azure.[This](http://forum.processing.org/one/topic/unable-to-load-pjs-sketch-files-lifetime-web-pde-invalid-xhr-status-404-message-in-browser.html) is the post that I found.I assume it is something related with permissions.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the .pde MIME type to your IIS config (web.config file) in Azure. It will look something like the below XML block:

`<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".pde" mimeType="application/x-processing" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>`

I'm not sure what the exact mime type is for that file, but the issue is that the MIME type isn't configured, and IIS will block unknown MIME types by default.

Comment: Dear Urit;
Thanks for your answer. I think that will most probably work but I don't know how to reach web.config file. I am using sublime text not visual studio and I use git to push my code to azure web pages. Do you know how can I reach and manipulate web.config file. I saw some examples over the internet but they use Visual studio. Is it enough if I just create web.config file from scratch and push it to the server.

Comment: Yes, the web config is just a text file, so you can edit it with sublime text and push it to your git repo. You might be able to use that snippet with only minor edits. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815179 on how to make a blank web.config.